# My callback function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I am do a nodeJS application, in which there is a call back function to persist the value to the database(**MongoDB**). The callback function as below:

```
exports.add = function(student, cb) {
    var collection = db.get().collection('students');
    collection.insert(student, function(err) {
        if (err) {
           throw err;
        }
        console.log("Record added");
    });
}
```

The above call back function is called from the another fuction as below:

```
router.post("/add", function(req,res){
    var student = req.body;
    Students.add(student, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var respOut = JSON.stringify({id:student.id});
        console.log("respOut");
        res.send(respOut);
    });
});
```

The call back function is called from the above bolded(Students.add) section. Currently I am able to persist the data on to the DB. But not getting any output on the console( given console out as -> `console.log("respOut");` or any response in the UI(from above code). Is there any problem with my call back function? or I am missing anything?

Comment: you are not calling cb(err) in exports.add, it should be after or before your console.log("Record added")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `cb` in your `Students.add` method.

The easiest would be to just pass the callback through to `collection.insert`:

```
exports.add = function(student, cb) {
    var collection = db.get().collection('students');
    collection.insert(student, cb);
}
```